# If there is null in the result of join then take left value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, null

My issue is

I have a table1 with data

```
Num Value
----
1 B
2 С
3 D
4 F
5 G
```

And another one table2

```
Num Value
----
1 K
2 Z
6 D
10 F
15 G
```

In the result I have

```
Num Value1 Value2
----
1 B K
2 С Z
3 D null
4 F null
5 G null
```

But how should I join tables to have default value instead of null, for instance the same as it is given to the left

```
1 B K
2 С Z
3 D D
4 F F
5 G G
```

What should I write in SQL?

I initially try like

```
SELECT t1.Num, t1.Value 
FROM table1 t1 
RIGHT JOIN  table2 t2 ON t1.Num = t2.Num
```

Comment: Edit you question and show the query you are using.

Comment: SELECT t1.Num, t1.Value 
FROM table1 t1 
RIGHT JOIN  table2 t2 ON t1.Num = t2.Num

Comment: Are you not just after `ISNULL`/`COALESCE`?

Comment: Not only, but if there is a null in the result of JOIN I need left value from t1 there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `coalesce()`:

```
select t1.num, t1.value as value1,
       coalesce(t2.value, t1.value) as value2
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.num = t2.num;
```